# Storing dll files on Blob storage

Tags: runtime, cloud, blob, azure-storage, .net-assembly

I'm storing dll files on blob storage. Is there any way I can add them as reference in my c# class library.

I'm able to load it via web client and use it via reflection. However I also would like to add few dll's in other class libraries.

Please let me know if there's any way to add reference to dll stored in blob. Either runtime or compile time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way to "add reference" to a dll that isn't already accessible locally to the build process. At runtime as you've already found, you can dynamically load and invoke code from the dll. If Types in that dll implement a well know interface that you can compile against (e.g. a shared interface library) at runtime you can dynamically create instances that implement that interface from the assembly you load.

Comment: Thank you Mathew. Is there any other way I can use aeemblies stored in blob other than the way I discussed of loading it via webclient

Comment: No. You'll need to load the assemblies into your app dynamically as you are doing now.